# gcp console, trying to build a project and gives no disp space error

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to build a golang project on my gcp console.  However when I run the build command I get the following error `no space left on device`, when I run the df command I see the following.

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay                             60G   44G   17G  73% /
tmpfs                               64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs                              7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                           60G   44G   17G  73% /root
/dev/disk/by-id/google-home-part1  4.8G  4.5G   38M 100% /home
/dev/root                          2.0G  1.2G  820M  59% /lib/modules
shm                                 64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              7.9G  940K  7.9G   1% /google/host/var/run
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this, and is there something I can do to free up some disk space? I assume this is the location `/dev/disk/by-id/google-home-part1`?  I am trying to build the go project in the `/home/user1/gopath` directory.

Answer (score 2):

The df command is showing that you have the /home directory full. You must free some space to use it.

```
Filesystem                         Use%  Mounted on

/dev/disk/by-id/google-home-part1  100%  /home
```